# How to edit pmml model file using xml parser

Tags: python, xml, pmml

I want to remove some nodes from a pmml file that I generated. So I tried to use xml parser in python:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse('treedemo.pmml')
for inter in tree.findall('DataDictionary'):
    print(inter)
```

It turns out that the print output nothing, which means the xml parser didn't work. the pmml file is [here](https://github.com/kaiwang0112006/mytranfor/blob/master/treedemo.pmml). Suppose I want to delete

```
<Interval closure="closedClosed" leftMargin="21.0" rightMargin="46.0"/>
```

from

```
<DataField name="fk_057_nearcontact_auth_expire_time" optype="continuous" dataType="float">
    <Interval closure="closedClosed" leftMargin="21.0" rightMargin="46.0"/>
</DataField>
```

Can pmml file be edit and modified by python?

Comment: But after you modify the pmml file, is it guaranteed to be a valid pmml file? Why not edit at the source, from where you have made the pmml

Comment: Yes, I can guarante the pmml file is valid and I don't see options to do it at the source

Answer (score 0):

Rather than developing custom XML manipulation code, you should learn about an existing technology called [XSL Transformations](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/) (XSLT).

In brief, you need to create an XSL document, which specifies XML manipulation actions. You can then apply this XSL document to one or more XML documents (including PMML documents) using command-line XSLT tools. For example, on GNU/Linux systems you can use the `xsltproc` tool.

An XSL document for deleting `Interval` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pmml="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2">
    <!-- By default, copy all -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- However, in case of the PMML Interval element, take no (copy-) action -->
    <xsl:template match="pmml:Interval"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Be sure to configure the value of the `pmml` namespace prefix to match that of your PMML documents. The above example applies to PMML schema version 4.2 documents.

Then, apply the stylesheet to PMML files (command syntax `xsltproc <XSL file> <PMML file(s)>`):

```
$ xsltproc --output test-mod.pmml test.xsl test.pmml
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's risky to play with pmml file, just be careful about it.

You can use BeautifulSoup.
for your specific goal, the tag 'Interval' appear only once, so you can find this tag in only one step, and then extract it:

```
# import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# open and read the file
inf = open(r'treedemo.xml', 'r')
txt = inf.read()
inf.close()
# prepare the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'xml')
# now find the tag you want to remove, in this case it's easy, since the tag 'Interval' is unique across your pmml file:
interval = soup.find('Interval')
# remove the tag
interval.extract()
# write the updated pmml file
with open(r'treedemo_clean.xml', "w") as outf:
    outf.write(str(soup))
```

- The output will have no indents unless you will use outf.write(str(soup.prettify()))
- I will not recommend to use prettify. might mess up the pmml
- In case the tag is not unique then you have to find it carefully, in order to avoid deleting the wrong tag and brake your pmml.
- There is nothing wrong with the field you want to remove. it shows statistics from your training data set. you can set the flag with_statistics=False